# Configure parallel execution of tests and classes in testng.xml

Tags: multithreading, selenium, webdriver, testng

My testng.xml is as given below:

```
<suite name="Automation Suite" allow-return-values="true" verbose="1" parallel="tests" thread-count="2">
    <test name="Login Test cases 01">
        <parameter name="Operating_System" value="Windows 8"/>
        <parameter name="Browser_Name" value="Internet Explorer"/>
        <parameter name="Browser_Version" value="11"/>
        <parameter name="Base_URL" value="https://www.google.com"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="com.automation.tool.Automation_01"/>
            <class name="com.automation.tool.Automation_02"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Login Test cases 02">
        <parameter name="Operating_System" value="Windows XP"/>
        <parameter name="Browser_Name" value="Mozilla Firefox"/>
        <parameter name="Browser_Version" value="27"/>
        <parameter name="Base_URL" value="https://www.google.com"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="com.automation.tool.Automation_01"/>
            <class name="com.automation.tool.Automation_02"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Currently the tests are getting executed in parallel. But I wish to execute the classes also in parallel as below:

> Thread 01 : Test 01 Class 01
>   Thread 02 : Test 01 Class 02
>   Thread 03 : Test 02 Class 01
>   Thread 04 : Test 02 Class 02

Please let me know, how to configure this setup.

Comment: Did you try to set `parallel="classes"`? http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-tests

Comment: I tried it. But it does not work.

Comment: thread count is 2 in your xml file. Have you tried making this 4 ?

Comment: Please clarify how do you handle selenium driver creation and sharing it between various classes ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Got it now...

```
<suite name="Automation Suite" allow-return-values="true" verbose="1" parallel="tests" thread-count="2">
    <test name="Login Test cases 01" parallel="classes" thread-count="2">
        <parameter name="Operating_System" value="Windows 8"/>
        <parameter name="Browser_Name" value="Internet Explorer"/>
        <parameter name="Browser_Version" value="11"/>
        <parameter name="Base_URL" value="https://www.google.com"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="com.automation.tool.Automation_01"/>
            <class name="com.automation.tool.Automation_02"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Login Test cases 02" parallel="classes" thread-count="2">
        <parameter name="Operating_System" value="Windows XP"/>
        <parameter name="Browser_Name" value="Mozilla Firefox"/>
        <parameter name="Browser_Version" value="27"/>
        <parameter name="Base_URL" value="https://www.google.com"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="com.automation.tool.Automation_01"/>
            <class name="com.automation.tool.Automation_02"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Answer (score 0):

In suite tag change the "parallel" attribute value from "tests" to "classes" for example:

If you wish to execute

1. tests in parallel then use = **parallel="tests"**
2. classes in parallel then use = **parallel="classes"**
3. Methods in parallel then use = **parallel="methods"**